# Plotly Dash: Charts don't update when button is pressed

Tags: python, plotly-dash, plotly-python, candlestick-chart, tiingo

After changing the stock ticker the user should be able to press the enter button to have the graph change to display the new tickers data. The graph will update once I interact with it such as zooming in so I know the data is being updated but for some reason it won't update the graph display when the enter button is initially pressed like I want it to.

```py
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import plotly.express as px
import key
from tiingo import TiingoClient
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import market_holidays
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Link(
        rel='stylesheet',
        href='https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css'
    ),
    dcc.Input(id='input-box', value='SPY', type='text', placeholder='Enter a stock ticker'),
    html.Button('Enter', id='enter_button'),
    html.Div(),
    html.P('4 Searches a Minute'),
    dcc.Graph(id='candle-graph', animate=True, style={"backgroundColor": "#1a2d46", 'color': '#ffffff'}, ),
    dcc.Interval(
        id='interval-component',
        interval=1 * 60000,  # in milliseconds
        n_intervals=0),
    html.Div([
        html.P('Developed by: ', style={'display': 'inline', 'color': 'white'}),
        html.A('Kaden Baskett', href='https://kadenbaskett.wixsite.com/mysite'),
        html.P(' - ', style={'display': 'inline', 'color': 'white'}),
        html.A('kadenbaskett@gmail.com', href='mailto:kadenbaskett@gmail.com')
    ], className="twelve columns",
        style={'fontsize': 18, 'padding-top': 20}
    ),
])

api_key = key.api_key
config = {'session': True, 'api_key': api_key}
client = TiingoClient(config)
timeDiff = 6


# chartFrequency = '5min'


@app.callback(
    Output('candle-graph', 'figure'),
    Input('enter_button', 'n_clicks'),
    state=[State(component_id='input-box', component_property='value')]
)
def update_figure(n_clicks, input_value):
    ticker = input_value.upper()
    price_data = client.get_dataframe(ticker, startDate="2021-08-19",
                                      endDate="2021-08-20", frequency='1min')

    price_data.index = price_data.index - timedelta(hours=timeDiff)

    chartCalendar = market_holidays.Calendar("2020-01-01", "2021-12-31")
    holidayDates = chartCalendar.get_holidays()

    fig = go.Figure(go.Candlestick(
        x=price_data.index,
        open=price_data['open'],
        high=price_data['high'],
        low=price_data['low'],
        close=price_data['close']

    ))

    fig.update_xaxes(
        rangeslider_visible=False,
        rangebreaks=[
            # NOTE: Below values are bound (not single values), ie. hide x to y
            dict(bounds=["sat", "mon"]),  # hide weekends, eg. hide sat to before mon
            dict(bounds=[14, 7.5], pattern="hour"),
            dict(values=holidayDates)
        ]
    )

    fig.update_layout(title=ticker + " Analysis", template='plotly_dark', yaxis_title=ticker + " price (USD)")

    return fig


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: I can't run your code exactly, because I don't have your API key, but I was able to run it with the callback just returning `n_clicks` as children, and it runs fine.

Comment: I don't know why it wasn't working. When I cam back a few days later it ran with no code change and still is now